# How do I make the calculation for this distance matrix faster?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, distance

I am working on a clustering task with geospatial data. I want to compute my own distance matrix that combines both geographical and temporal distance. My data (`np.array`) contains latitude, longitude, and timestamp. A sample of my DataFrame `df` ([dict to reproduce](https://justpaste.it/bc1fr)):

```
        latitude    longitude   timestamp
412671  52.506136   6.068709    2017-01-01 00:00:23.518
412672  52.503316   6.071496    2017-01-01 00:01:30.764
412673  52.505122   6.068912    2017-01-01 00:02:30.858
412674  52.501792   6.068605    2017-01-01 00:03:38.194
412675  52.508105   6.075160    2017-01-01 00:06:41.116
```

I currently use the following code:

```
np_data = df.to_numpy()

# convert latitudes and longitudes to radians
lat_lon_rad = np.radians(np_data[:,:2].astype(float))

# compute Haversine distance matrix
haversine_matrix = haversine_distances(lat_lon_rad)
haversine_matrix /= np.max(haversine_matrix)

# compute time difference matrix
timestamps = np_data[:,2]
time_matrix = np.abs(np.subtract.outer(timestamps, timestamps)) # This line is SLOW
time_matrix /= np.max(time_matrix)

combined_matrix = 0.5 * haversine_matrix + 0.5 * time_matrix
```

This produces the desired result. However, when my data set is 1000 rows, this code takes +- 25 seconds to complete, mainly due to the calculation of the `time_matrix` (the haversine matrix is very fast). The problem is: I have to work with data sets of +- 200-500k rows. Using only the Haversine function is then still fine, but calculating my `time_matrix` will take way too long.

My question: **how do I speed up the calculation of the `time_matrix`?** I cannot find any way to perform the `np.subtract.outer(timestamps, timestamps)` calculation faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about converting the timestamps to floats and using Numpy's broadcasting feature to compute your time differences? The integer representation of time avoids the costly overhead associated using pandas timestamps. i.e

```
timestamps_sec = np.array([(ts - pd.Timestamp("1970-01-01")) // pd.Timedelta("1s") for ts in np_data[:, 2]])
timestamps_sec = timestamps_sec[:, np.newaxis]
```

Now you can compute the time difference matrix using broadcasting

```
time_matrix = np.abs(timestamps_sec - timestamps_sec.T)
time_matrix = time_matrix.astype(float)  # Convert to float to avoid integer division
time_matrix /= np.max(time_matrix)
```